# Word/phrase to describe the kind of joy that you feel when someone you like or love shows you an act of kindness or love

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests, diction

In my country, we call it “kilig.” When a guy, for instance, unexpectedly smiles at a girl who happens to have feelings for him, chances are the girl will feel so jubilant she would scream inside and smile.

Joyous, jubilant, and happy are too general to describe that specific feeling (you feel toward a person you like) that I want to describe using a “naturally occurring” word or phrase.

Can you suggest some terms?

Comment: Your question is tagged with single-word-request, but you mention a word or phrase in the question itself. I'd suggest either removing the single word request tag or adding a phrase tag.

Comment: Sorry about that. There, I already added “phrase-requests” tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any single word that has this specific meaning, but there are various phrases that convey the idea. A common one is **my heart skipped a beat**. While this term is also used to describe a medical condition, it's widely recognized as being a metaphor for a sudden, intense emotional response to an event, often of a romantic nature. It is a very common metaphor in [song lyrics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqXWsFg7tI8) and [poetry](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/my-heart-skipped-a-beat-3/).

"Bobby smiled at me and my heart skipped a beat."

Answer (score 0):

Such a natural romantic excitement can be expressed by the words:

**Exhilarate** https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exhilarate

> *Meaning*: make (someone) feel **very** happy, animated, or elated.
>
> > *Usage*: "she was exhilarated by the day's events."

**Thrill**
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thrill

> *Meaning*: A wave or nervous tremor of emotion or sensation.
>
> > *Usage*:"a thrill of excitement ran through her"

Or how about the word **Kilig** itself? :)

The English language has borrowed this word from the Philippines.

**Kilig** https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kilig

> *Meaning*: (of a person) exhilarated or elated by an exciting or romantic experience.
>
> > *Usage*:"I get **kilig** every time I hear this song."

Comment: But “exhilarate” and “thrill” don’t seem to capture instantly exactly what “kilig” really means. “Kilig” always has to do with sweetness or romance. Exhilarate and thrill are also too general they can be used in different contexts.

Comment: @JonasSergio it is very exquisite and unique word and that is the very reason Kilig was included in English language (OED).

Comment: @JonasSergio Thrill is more related to Kilig and it **tries** to capture the meaning of Kilig.

Comment: I hadn’t known until now that kilig has already been added in Oxforddictiknaries.com. But does this mean “kilig” is now officially recognized as an English word?

Comment: @JonasSergio yes, you can use it as a English word now :)

Comment: @JonasSergio if you like the answer then you can accept it by clicking *correct mark* :)